# Python: Converting string into decimal number

Tags: python, string, floating-point, decimal

I have a python list with strings in this format:

```
A1 = [' "29.0" ',' "65.2" ',' "75.2" ']
```

How do I convert those strings into decimal numbers to perform arithmetic operations on the list elements?

Answer (score 107):

If you want the result as the nearest binary floating point number use `float`:

```
result = [float(x.strip(' "')) for x in A1]
```

If you want the result stored exactly use [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) instead of `float`:

```
from decimal import Decimal
result = [Decimal(x.strip(' "')) for x in A1]
```

Comment: Tested this and realised it does not work because the strings have whitespace and extra quote marks in them.

Answer (score 24):

If you are converting price (in string) to decimal price then....

```
from decimal import Decimal

price = "14000,45"
price_in_decimal = Decimal(price.replace(',','.'))
```

> No need for the replace if your strings already use dots as a decimal separator

Comment: Doesn't this method lose the last 2 decimal places, resulting in a larger number?

Comment: `price_in_decimal = Decimal(price.replace(',','.'))` This is what @Nids intended I suppose. Replacing the , with .

Comment: @freerunner exactly!

Answer (score 5):

In Python there are two floating point datatypes `Float` and `Decimal`. The use case depends on the precision of decimal you want in your program. `Float` is quick and `Decimal` is precise.

To convert a string to a floating point number just do

```
import decimal
float('1.2')
decimal.Decimal('1.2')
```

Analysing `Float` and `Decimal` objects

```
>>> import sys
>>> from decimal import Decimal

>>> num = '1.2'

>>> float(num)
1.2

>>> Decimal(num)
Decimal('1.2')


>>> # Precision
>>> float(1.2)
1.2

>>> Decimal(1.2)
Decimal('1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875')


>>> # Memory usage
>>> sys.getsizeof(Decimal(num))
104

>>> sys.getsizeof(float(num))
24


>>> # Performance
>>> %timeit float(num)
140 ns ± 2.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

>>> %timeit Decimal(num)
192 ns ± 9.42 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

In your particular case you can use @Mark Byers solution.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `strip()` because of the extra bits in the strings.

```
A2 = [float(x.strip('"')) for x in A1]
```

Comment: You need to strip the extra space as well.

Comment: Tested with a cut-and-paste of the OP's example?  It didn't work as is.

Comment: @Mark, I've no idea what I did differently yesterday but it's not working now. Perhaps the question has been edited since I copied it.

Answer (score 2):

use the built in float() function in a list comprehension.

`A2 = [float(v.replace('"','').strip()) for v in A1]`

Answer (score 1):

`A2 = [float(x.strip('"')) for x in A1]` works, @Jake , but there are unnecessary 0s

Comment: Does not work with OP's _exact_ example.  Zeroes aren't "unnecessary".  `float` can't represent all decimals exactly in binary.  But see Mark Byers answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two floating-point data types. `Float` and `Decimal`. It depends on your program demand which one you want to use. `Decimal` provides a high level of accuracy and it's more precise than `Float`.

To convert a value string to float just do it:

```
num = "29.0"
print (float(num))
```

To convert string to decimal

```
from decimal import Decimal
num = "29.0"
print (Decimal(num))
```

For your specific question, you can use the below code. Both are working for me.

```
from decimal import Decimal
import re

result = [float(x.strip(' "')) for x in A1]
print(result)
#[29.0, 65.2, 75.2]


result = [Decimal(x.strip(' "')) for x in A1]
print(result)
#[Decimal('29.0'), Decimal('65.2'), Decimal('75.2')]


result = [float(re.search(r'\d+.\d+',number).group()) for number in A1]
print(result)
#[29.0, 65.2, 75.2]

result = [Decimal(re.search(r'\d+.\d+',number).group()) for number in A1]
print(result)
#[Decimal('29.0'), Decimal('65.2'), Decimal('75.2')]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are converting string to float:

```
import re
A1 = [' "29.0" ',' "65.2" ',' "75.2" ']
float_values = [float(re.search(r'\d+.\d+',number).group()) for number in A1]
print(float_values)
>>> [29.0, 65.2, 75.2]
```