# Auction program question, need help in checking a string - number from sub list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list consisting of sublists. I need to find the largest element in a specific position in the sublist. I have put the main list inside for loop, so I can manipulate the sublist directly. But the list is taking string type so it is not able to give me the largest number when I use the Max Function.

```
each_entry :
[['10', '1', 'SELL', 'toaster_1', '10.00', '20'], 
['12', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '7.50'], 
['13', '5', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '12.50'], 
['17', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '20.00']]
[['15', '8', 'SELL', 'tv_1', '250.00', '20'], 
['18', '1', 'BID', 'tv_1', '150.00'], 
['19', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '200.00'], 
['21', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '300.00']]
```

```
for each_bid_item in dictlist:
    for each_entry in each_bid_item:
        initial_time = (each_entry[0][0])
        max_time = (each_entry[0][5])
        reserve_price = (each_entry[0][4])
        sell_item = (each_entry[0][3])
```

When I type

```
print(max(each_entry[0][4]))
```

```
Output :  
1 
5
```

In a nutshell, I need to find the highest bid price for first and the second sublist.

Comment: [mre]? the max of "10.00" is 1 - works as desinged. Do you know how to convert a text into a number?

Comment: [python-converting-string-into-decimal-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643991/python-converting-string-into-decimal-number) - do that for all of them and then get the max from it.

Comment: thank you patrick. No i did not know. I am new to python. Let me check it out. Thanks for your kind reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily traverse the sublist to find the max value.

```
each_entry = [['10', '1', 'SELL', 'toaster_1', '10.00', '20'],
              ['12', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '7.50'],
              ['13', '5', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '12.50'],
              ['17', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '20.00']]
max_bid = 0
for entry in each_entry:
    sell_price = float(entry[4])
    if sell_price > max_bid:
        max_bid = sell_price

print(max_bid)
```

Output:

```
20.0
```